# ASP.NET MVC How to check for Null on bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry for this question but im stuck.

As my view loads dynamic controls, they may or may not exist when doing a post(Save),
So I need to check if the Key\Value exists before trying to get the value.
the below code breaks, but it shows what im trying to do

```
public class AccountFormBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        AccountEdit updateAccount = new AccountEdit();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingContext.ValueProvider.("ConfirmationMessage").ConvertTo(typeof(string)) as string))
        {
            updateAccount.EmailSettings.nMessage = (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Message").ConvertTo(typeof(string));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("blah");

    string a = string.Empty;

    if(value != null)
        a = value.AttemptedValue;

    return a;
}
```